# Processing: Performance issues with background()

Tags: processing

I'm creating a stereoscopic test application where the scene is rendered into a `PGraphics left` and a `PGraphics right` with different camera angles for the two eye points. The two images is then combined into a side-by-side output in the `draw()` function.

The scene consists of a pre-rendered background, stored in a separate `PGraphics`, rendered once, and a rotating `box()` rendered for each frame.

The problem is that the call to `gfx.background(gfxBackground);` in `render()` is very CPU intensive. If I replace it with a `gfx.background(0);` call, the sketch runs smoothly.

My assumption was that blit'ing data from one `PGraphics` to another would be done with hardware acceleration, but it seems it isn't. Am I doing something wrong?

My sketch:

```java
PGraphics leftBackground;
PGraphics rightBackground;
PGraphics left;
PGraphics right;

int sketchWidth()       { return 1920; }
int sketchHeight()      { return 1200; }
int sketchQuality()     { return 8;    }
String sketchRenderer() { return P3D;  }

void setup()
{
  noCursor();

  leftBackground = createGraphics(width / 2, height, P3D);
  renderBackground(leftBackground, "L");

  rightBackground = createGraphics(width / 2, height, P3D);
  renderBackground(rightBackground, "R");

  left  = createGraphics(width / 2, height, P3D);
  left.beginDraw();
  left.endDraw();
  left.camera(-10, 0, 220,
                0, 0,   0,
                0, 1,   0);

  right = createGraphics(width / 2, height, P3D);
  right.beginDraw();
  right.endDraw();
  right.camera( 10, 0, 220,
                 0, 0,   0,
                 0, 1,   0);

}

void draw()
{
  render(left, leftBackground);
  render(right, rightBackground);
  image(left, 0, 0);
  image(right, left.width, 0);
}

void renderBackground(PGraphics gfx, String str)
{
  gfx.beginDraw();
  gfx.background(0);

  gfx.stroke(255);
  gfx.noFill();
  gfx.rect(0, 0, gfx.width, gfx.height);

  gfx.scale(0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
  gfx.textSize(40);
  gfx.fill(255);
  gfx.text(str, 30, 40);
  gfx.endDraw();
}

void render(PGraphics gfx, PGraphics gfxBackground)
{
  gfx.beginDraw();
  gfx.background(gfxBackground);
  gfx.scale(0.5, 1, 1);
  gfx.rotateY((float)frameCount / 100);
  gfx.rotateX((float)frameCount / 90);
  gfx.stroke(255);
  gfx.fill(0);
  gfx.box(30);
  gfx.endDraw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple options to achieve the same visual output.
Here are a few options:

Simply overlay the "L"/"R" text:

in draw():

```
  render(left, bgl);
  render(right, bgr);
  image(right, 0, 0);
  image(right, left.width, 0);
  text("L",100,100);
  text("R",width/2+100,100);
```

using gfx.background(0) in render().

PGraphics extends PImage so instead of

`gfx.background(gfxBackground);`

you can use

```
gfx.image(gfxBackground,xoffset,yoffset);
```

You will need to offset because of the camera call, also, you will need to translate the box in Z direction since by default it will be at (0,0,0) and will intersect with the quad rendering the background image.

If you want to go deeper and find other bottlenecks sample the CPU using `jvisualvm` (if you have the JDK installed and PATH set to it you should be able to run this from terminal/commandline, otherwise there's an application in YOUR_JDK_INSTALL_PATH\bin).
Take a couple snapshots at different intervals and compare performance. You might find some other draw commands that could be changed to gain a few ms per frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, what I'm really interested in, is why the blit'ing from one PGraphics to another is so slow. It seems to me that this operation should be fast. So to clarify the question, maybe I should ask some thing along the lines of 'How do I copy from one off-screen buffer to another off-screen buffer using hardware accelleration?'

Thanks for the jvisualvm tip :-)

Comment: No worries, feel free to vote/mark as you see fit ;) Also, just spotted the reason why background(PImage) can't be hardware accelerated. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PGraphics.java#L7017) PGraphics uses set(0,0,image) as it inherits set from it's parent class PImage and [set()](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PImage.java#L964) uses `System.arraycopy`. Above I recommended `gfx.image(gfxBackground,x,y);` which [renders a textured quad](http://goo.gl/z25Cu8)